# Add to cart not showing in Safari, does in FireFox and Chrome

Tags: html, button, shopping-cart, hidden

I'm fairly new to all of this and am clueless where to begin to have a div show in Safari. The only thing I really have changed is to add a SSL, Dedicate IP, and added the Autoptimizer plugin. Before that the div worked.

Example Image page:

[1937 Chevy Coupe](http://www.imagerybycharly.com/print/1937-chevy-coupe/)

How it works:

After making the selections on an image to purchase, the quantity and add to cart button div is supposed to appear. It does work in FireFox and Chrome, but does not in Safari.

Issue:

I'm using WooCommerce for my shopping cart. When I use the Inspect Element in Safari, with selections made to purchase, the div for single_variation_wrap to show the "add to cart" and quantity retains a display none. When I remove the none the div appears.

What I need to know:

Why does this only happen in Safari? And how would I correct this?

I'd really appreciate assistance with this issue! Thanks!

UPDATE: I believe I've fixed the issue, but still would appreciate anyone making sure for me. Thanks!!

Comment: This doesn't work for me in any browser. You are getting another JS error though in  autoptimize_0afdbaba40c3a3030e0c4addf3047cf3.js. I would resolve that first as it may have a knock on effect.

Comment: Thanks haxbh! I found that too was causing an error. Definitely not good it didn't work at all for you. Have contacted the Autoptimizer plugin dev